# SWIG return unsigned char * from C to Python

Tags: python, c, swig

I'm running into a problem with generating an interface for python with underlying C code.
I have the following pieces of code:

prov.h

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

unsigned char *out();
```

prov.c

```
#include "prov.h"

unsigned char *out()
{
    unsigned char *bytes="Hello";
    unsigned char *data=NULL;
    data=calloc(6,sizeof(char));
    if(data) {
        strncpy(data,bytes,6);
    }
    return data;
}
```

prov.i

```
%module prov
%{
#include "prov.h"
%}

unsigned char *out();
```

And I generate the .so as shown below:

```
$ swig -python prov.i
$ gcc -fpic -c prov.c  prov_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.7
$ gcc -shared prov.o prov_wrap.o -o _prov.so
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import prov
>>> s=prov.out()
>>> s
<Swig Object of type 'unsigned char *' at 0x7fb241dbff90>
```

Now the problem is that when I try to view the returned string, s from my C function, it doesn't seem to show it as a python string object (I expected when I print s the output should be 'Hello'). Can anyone please help me out with returning unsigned char * to python calling code?

Answer (score 1):

Either return `char*` instead, or you can apply the `char*` typemaps to `unsigned char*`.  You'll also want `%newobject` to let Python know to free the returned pointer after converting the return result to a Python object.

```
%module prov
%{
#include "prov.h"
%}

%apply char* {unsigned char*};    
%newobject out;
unsigned char *out();
```